# Product of three Poisson distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

Product of two Poisson distributions is a Bessel function:

$$ \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-f} f^r }{\Gamma(r+1)} \frac{e^{-g} g^r }{\Gamma(r+1)} = e^{-f-g} I_0\left(2 \sqrt{f g} \right) $$

What I need is the product of **three**:

$$ \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-f} f^r }{\Gamma(r+1)} \frac{e^{-g} g^r }{\Gamma(r+1)} \frac{e^{-h} h^r }{\Gamma(r+1)} = \quad\mbox{?}$$

Is there a known special function? Any idea?

Comment: It's doubtful that the answer is simpler than a hypergeometric function. Curiously though, are you really interested in the probability that 3 Poisson's are equal, or are you trying to find the distribution of the product of three Poisson random variables?

Comment: @Alex I'm optimizing a Bayesian cost function involving a Bayes least squares solution. The integral equation I need to solve happens to contain such expression.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess according to the definition
$$_pF_q(a_1,\ldots,a_p;b_1,\ldots,b_q;z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_n\dots(a_p)_n}{(b_1)_n\dots(b_q)_n} \, \frac {z^n} {n!}$$
you have a generalized hypergeometric function:
$$\sum _{r=0}^{\infty } \frac{f^r g^r h^r}{(r!)^3}= \ _0F_2(\cdot \ ;1,1;f g h)$$
And there is no way you can simplify it without using some approximations.